# Option for "No Acceptable Answer"

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Having the percentage of Accepted answers featuring so prominently in a user's profile puts users under pressure to accept just any answer - when there is no good enough answer -in order that their percentage doesn't go down.

My problem is that - at times - there is really no acceptable answer. I think there should be an option to say that the person who asked the question doesn't think that any answer is good enough to be marked as Accepted, in the same time, the user's percentage doesn't go down because he didn't just ask a question and disappear, he actually cared enough about giving feedback (it's actually better feedback than accepting a mediocre answer).

Comment: Related: [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Answer (score 7):

Let me start off by saying that no user should ever feel pressured into accepting an answer. No user should ever be pressured into accepting an answer. That being said, I fully agree that the visible accept rate has that effect. And using quite a significant number of my comment flags on inappropriate accept rate comments and pestering, I see such comments on a daily basis. Even more uncomfortable is the fact that this is not limited to newer users, but there are several very high-rep users who are involved in such activities.

All that being said, I don't think that what you propose will help much at all. You can already show your active participation in a question by actively participating in a question. Not just wait for answers to come in, but to actively point out how they do not answer your question. Collaborate with your answerers, address their comments, etc.

While it's true that with what you propose you won't have a negative accept rate on display (whatever qualifies "negative"), explicitly marking a question as having "no acceptable answers" when several users might have done their best to give you an acceptable answer is not going to send a positive message either.

If you have accepted all you can accept, and you are actively trying to get your questions answered, the problem is not with you. And we should not expect you to do anything else to prevent such comments. The problem is with those commenting on accept rate and those pestering others into accepting answers under some form of threat of no longer answering your questions. That is who we should deal with.

Comment: I really don't let it get under my skin, but a lot of people do care about it like you noticed. and as I told @animuson if SO choose to put acceptance rate among three highlighted variables for the person posing a question, then SO is implying that it is important (as important as points and badges)

Comment: @kabaros Which is exactly why I have made the proposal I linked to in my comment under your question. I personally very actively hunt and flag/nuke such comments, as I do track down and delete any such content from answers. So I agree there is the problem, but I don't think your solution will have the intended effect.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option for that: **not accepting an answer**. The minor effect leaving the question unaccepted has on your accept rate doesn't mean anything. It's just *one* question. It's not like you asked a hundred questions and decided "none of these answer my question" on every one. If you did, maybe you have a problem with your questions.

If you've solved your problem and none of the answers actually answer your question, **post your own answer** and accept that. If you really want an answer still, offer a bounty to draw attention to it. You have so many options, stop focusing on the accept rate percentage.

Comment: I don't focus on it but I see many users asking people: "to have better acceptance rate in order to get better answer", and I have a couple of questions I asked and never marked them as answered because I didn't get a satisfactory answer and I won't change that. I am not focusing on this, SO is. Because if acceptance rate is one of three variables highlighted for the person asking a question then SO is - in fact - putting an unnecessary emphasis on it.

Comment: So flag the comments and move on. Any comments which contain the phrase "accept rate" get auto-removed.

Comment: you're missing the point here: i DO move on. That's not what I'm discussing here.

Comment: Is this a discussion or a feature request though? The feature you suggested is a terrible idea, which is why you're getting downvotes. The issue behind the feature that you seem more interested in has been discussed quite a bit already here on Meta. If your only concern is with people bugging you about the accept rate, and not with the feature, then I suggest you just support Bart's proposal in the related question, because you are right, the accept rate is only important by the slightest of margins, and causes way more problems than provides information.